# Norm of a matrix and its rank-1 approximation

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, svd

### Problem

This looks like a stupid question, but the following is not straightforward to me
$$
\Vert \mathbf{W}\Vert_p \geq \Vert \mathbf{\tilde{W}}\Vert_p, \Vert \mathbf{W}\Vert_F \geq \Vert \mathbf{\tilde{W}}\Vert_F
$$
where $\mathbf{W}=\sum_{i=1}^r s_i \mathbf{u}_i\mathbf{v}_i^T$ ($r$ is number of non-zero singular values) and $\mathbf{\tilde{W}}= s_1 \mathbf{u}_1\mathbf{v}_1^T$

### What I Have Done

I tried to write $\mathbf{W}$ in the following
$$
\mathbf{W}=\mathbf{\tilde{W}}+\sum_{i=2}^r s_i \mathbf{u}_i\mathbf{v}_i^T
$$
But something like 
$$\Vert \mathbf{\tilde{W}}+\sum_{i=2}^r s_i \mathbf{u}_i\mathbf{v}_i^T\Vert_p \geq \Vert \mathbf{\tilde{W}}\Vert_p$$ does not seem to hold.

Could someone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing $\| \cdot \|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.  Is $\|\cdot\|_p$ the operator norm corresponding to the $p$-norm on vectors?

Comment: I am not familiar with "operator norm", but as I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm), I think the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W = U \Sigma V^T$ is the singular value decomposition of $W$, 
then $$\|W\|_F^2 = \text{Tr}(W W^T) = \text{Tr}(U \Sigma^2 U^T)
= \text{Tr}(\Sigma^2) = \sum_i s_i^2$$
while $\|\tilde{W}\|_F^2 = s_1^2$.

EDIT: It's not true for the $p$-norm.  For example, in dimension $2$ take $p=1$ with ${\bf u}_1 = {\bf v}_1 = (3/5, 4/5)^T$, ${\bf u}_2 = {\bf v}_2 = (4/5, -3/5)^T$, $s_1 = s_2 = 1$.  Then ${\bf W} = I$ has norm $1$, but 
$$ \widetilde{\bf W} = \pmatrix{9/25 & 12/25\cr 12/25 & 16/25\cr}$$ has norm $28/25$, with $$\widetilde{\bf W} \pmatrix{0\cr 1\cr} = \pmatrix{12/25\cr 16/25}$$

Comment: Thank you. Does this argument also hold for matrix $p$-norm?